# ListLogPlot bug? Points outside PlotRange change colours

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, plot-themes

Consider the following example

```
ListLogPlot[{{Null}, {{1, 4}, {2, 10}, {3, 20}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 10}, {5,
 20}}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {3, 11}}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

in Mathematica 10.2 it results in the following plot with different colours for the two top points. How can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: The issue is still in MMA 11.3. And it is more evident when `Frame->False, Axes->True`. Those points should not be there. I use macOS 10.13.4, in a iMac Intel i3. I suggest you contact support.

Comment: weird, note that those markers should not be there at all. It is putting a marker where the joining line hits the range boundary.

Answer (score 2):

the workaround:

```
data = {{Null}, {{1, 4}, {2, 10}, {3, 20}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 10}, {5, 
     20}}};
Show[{ListLogPlot[data,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {3, 11}}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False],
  ListLogPlot[data]}]
```

[image]